# Nakamura bike brand?

Tags: road-bike, used-bike, reliability

I'm looking for information about bike brand "Nakamura". I know it is sold in Norway (intersport.no), France (nakamura.fr, intersport.fr), somewhere in Canada. However, the internet is relatively quiet about it and usual bike review sites are usually not even mentioning it. 
It is generally considered a cheap brand, but apparently, they have (and have had) some higher-end models as well, most expensive currently in Norway's Intersport being 3000€ road bike with a carbon frame and (near) top components. So, there should be someone somewhere who knows more about them, right?

Comment: Are the same models marketed in all countries? Nakamura brand used to be sold in Finland too and I had the impression it was a distributor's house brand similar to Nishiki.

Comment: If I look at Intersport's pages, it is probably true that it is it's house brand. And yes, Intersport also seems to be in Finland and they list road bikes, but much smaller selection than Norway. But that kind of leaves the question open, because at least the more expensive models do not look like a "buy and throw away after season kind of equipment".

Comment: https://www.intersport.fr/sports/cycle/velos/vtt/ is the bike in question listed on here? The general census from other forums is avoid, a quick look on the link above shows the cheaper end using standard HG200 cassettes with tourney components. Much like many BSOs

Comment: @DanK It is more about the higher end road models, like these https://www.intersport.no/sykkel/sykler/landeveissykler/nakamura but I have already understood this place is not for buying advice, so I'm trying to understand the more general picture.

Comment: Ok, here is some explanation http://www.nakamura.fr/marque (google translate work's well).

Comment: In Finland Nakamura has a strong BSO reputation and unusually derogatory nickname. It looks like Intersport is trying to sell high end house brand bikes, but I don't get why they use the Nakamura name instead of inventing a new one. In Finland they tried similar with Nishiki brand and it didn't work well. 7.9kg is quite a lot for full carbon + Ultegra and size selection is very limited, I wonder if they understand serious bike market at all.

Comment: @ojs Thanks, I'm not sure about the weight, similarly priced carbon Cannondale in intersport.no is actually a bit heavier (8.4kg). And Trek of the similar price is also not lighter https://boasykler.no/produkt/trek-emonda-sl-6-disc-2019/

Comment: That's really surprising, my road bike with steel frame and year 2004 Veloce is 8.5 kg.

Comment: Last post here is quite relevant http://www.retrobike.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=241777

Comment: Look at the Pursuit 8.0 and 9.0 from 2012 here http://slidegur.com/doc/4748696/nakamura-2012 Not exactly BSOs.

Comment: Might be that they didn't completely destroy their reputation in Norway with the entry level hybrids set up by shoe salespeople.

Comment: @kakk11 I'm not sure there's a lot more to be said, unless someone happens to own one comes along and posts.   Did you end up buying one?

Comment: @Criggie Yep, I bought it. Lightweight bike, mostly carbon except for wheels. I have not used it too much, ca 1000km, the only thing that required work during this was the bottom bracket, which was trivial to replace once I got the right tools, and steering bracket needs work as well soon. I can add more details, even pictures if you are interested.

Comment: @kakk11 in the interests of getting a good answer for your question, I think that's a great idea.  Try adding what you would have liked to know when first asking the question, and it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I Have Nakamura custom made bike for my sister... Explorer? I´ll check it next time...

It was a pretty awesome deal back than from my sis´s bf...

It wasn´t been driven for 7-8 years and for the last 5-6 i am using it pretty reasonably.

Me being a 6´2 and 230-240lbs dude... jumping on and off the boardwalks all the time whilst driving kinda makes this bike amazing...

Its light weight and narrow build has surprised me to be holding after so many years...

Haven´t invested anything in it and it is still rolling at Nov. 2023...

Had it lubed up last year for 25e and that is it.

It is still with all original parts and i cannot be happier to be having it still...

Has simple basic front shimano and deore as the back shift... Therefore nothing special... But still... Amazing...

Only swapped brake pads once... maybe twice...

Cheerz!

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Stack Exchange sites do not work like a typical chat forum. You have some interesting content in what you posted, but it should be limited to just an answer to the original question. The additional superfluous information should be contained in an additional comment instead of the body of your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the info - If you have the chance to grab a photo and [edit] it into your answer that would be great too.